# How to apply for a skilled worker visa from India?

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas, skilled-migration

I'm a software engineer and I have 5 years working experience in the field. I just saw [Employment Base Visa](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/permanent-workers/employment-based-immigration-third-preference-eb-3), for which I think  I'm qualified to apply. But only one confusion I have is that before applying for this visa, do I need a job offer from a company in the USA or can I go without this, based only on my experience letter? Like in the picture below, this mentions a full-time job offer is required.

[image]

If a job offer is required before applying then how can I get this? I need suggestion and advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have the job offer first and then the company has to apply to the USA government for a visa for you.

There are scams and exploitative employers out there so be on your guard.

This site is global but has a lot of USA jobs and should flag ones with visa offered https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16735011